# How to solve $ax^x+bx+c=0$?

Tags: tetration, discriminant, hyperoperation

How can I solve
$$ax^x+bx+c=0$$
or
$$ax^{x^x}+bx^x+cx+d=0$$
where $x^x$ and $x^{x^x}$ - tetration? Is there analogue of discriminant for it?

Comment: I'd be absolutely flabbergasted if normal polynomial methods applied here. (And not to be discouraging, but this equation looks pretty nasty in general.)

Comment: Only numerical methods will do the job.